# how to set shopping cart rules to cater buy any 2 SKUs and get the 3rd SKUs from the rule for free?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I need to create a price rule that caters buy any 2 SKUs and get the 3rd SKUs from the rule for free? I tried many conditions and actions however i cant get the rules to work properly.

I have tried to use the Buy X and Get Y free option, however it only cater to one SKU meaning that customers can only order 3 of the same SKUs to get the 3rd one free. What i want is customer can get any 3 of the SKUs listed in the condition and get the 3rd one free.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set the condition tab as

Total qty of products matching all the following conditions is 3
sku is one of x,y, z

The action tab as

Action: percent discount
Amount 100
Step: 0
Max amount: 1
Apply to: sku is one of x,y, z

So it will work for 3 products.

Magento does not support the rule **Buy X get Y free** by default, so for advanced promotions you also may search magento connect  "special promotions"